# Gamilat stands under the platform?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

In the "Hidden Ones" DLC for Assassin's Creed: Origins, during the "Setting Sun" quest, an NPC (Gamilat) and I are trying to escape a pyramid. After finishing a platform puzzle and making it through a corridor filled with snakes, we ended up in another platform puzzle room.

When we entered, Bayek says tells Gamilat to stand on the platform and he will raise it up. Gamilat agrees and moves to the platform ... but since the platform is already suspended, he crouches underneath it. As a result, I can't lower the platform so that he can step on it. (When I tried, it just lowered on top of him; he didn't take the hint to move.)

I can't figure out how to get Gamilat to move out from under the platform. Is this possible or do I need to reload the quest from the last checkpoint?

[image: Gamilat crouching underneath the platform]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is a bug.**

While I've not found it documented, when I reloaded from the last quest objective I found that the platform was lowered to the ground:

[image: Platform held down by crates]

It is being pinned to the ground by a stack of slideable crates. These weren't present when I had previously entered the cave. This time, Gamilat was able to run over and step on the platform and I was able to complete the puzzle. Previously, since the crates simply didn't exist when I entered the cave, the two platforms were both unweighted and were hanging above the ground.

So, basically, if you enter this cave after the corridor with cobras, and the far platform is not lowered, reload your quest from the last objective. It reloads from the time you enter the room, so you don't lose any progress.